# tmux configuration

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to change the tmux colors on a computer I haven't visited in a while. In tmux man page I read that tmux will look for a `/etc/tmux.conf` and, if not found, would go to `~/.tmux.conf`. Since the `/etc` one does not exist, I wrote this line on my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g status-bg red
```

And the bar is still green. From then on, I tried a few variations of that command and how to spell the color name, all to no avail. Even tried specifying the conf with a `tmux -2 -f .tmux.conf`, also nothing.

Am I missing something obvious here?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your `$TERM` variable?

Comment: screen-256color

Answer (score 4):

That should be correct. Are you sure you restarted tmux (and not just detached and reattached), or reloaded the configuration from inside tmux? `ctrl-b` + `:` +  `source ~/.tmux.conf`

Also, does tmux report any syntax errors in your configuration upon startup?